# Win Server 2008 + IIS 7 + MVC3: what to install to deploy applications

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, asp.net-mvc

I'm newbie at deployment.

I have OS Windows Server 2008 R2 on my server with IIS 7. I have folder with .Net MVC3 web application. I created new pool, set Framework 4.0 for it. I created new website, chose physical path 'E:/site' and bound it to domain name. Then I copied folder with my .Net MVC3 site into 'E:/site'. But if I try open mydomain.com it doesn't work as MVC3 application. Usual HTML-pages work only.

I guess, I should install some components or programs to make server run web site as MVC application. Serever has already:

- MS .Net Framework 4 Client Profile;
- MS .Net Framework 4 Extended;
- MS Web Platform Installer 3.0.

Can anybody help me? What should I do else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either install the MVC Framework on the server itself, or you can do a "bin deploy" of the required assemblies from within Visual Studio. This definitely works with Visual Studio 2010, because I've done it before - your mileage may vary with earlier versions.

To do a bin deploy, right click on your project in Visual Studio and select **Add Deployable Dependencies**. From the dialog, choose **ASP.NET MVC** (don't worry about the other options, this is all you need). This will create a folder in your project called `_bin_deployableAssemblies` with the necessary DLL's to run MVC stuff.

Do a deploy afterwards and it should work. If not, the full yellow screen of death error text would be very helpful.

Comment: Thanks! I've installed ASP.NET MVC 3 and ASP.NET MVC 3 Pages. Therefore I see 403 error on mydomain.com. I can get .html files only (e.g. mydomain.com/page.html).

Comment: I ran 'aspnet_regiis -i -enable' from windows/microsoft.net/framework64/v4.0.30319 else. So, it works fine. Thanks!